# TypeError: only valid absolute URLs can be requested

Tags: node.js, next.js, openid-connect, openid-client-js

Getting the following error with the latest [openid-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/openid-client) in a next-js application.

```bash
Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: only valid absolute URLs can be requested

  3 | 
  4 | const oidcConfig = async () => {
> 5 |   const issuer = await Issuer.discover('https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration');
    |                              ^
```

Here's the code chunk I'm using.

```js
const { Issuer } = require('openid-client');

const oidcConfig = async () => {
    const issuer = await Issuer.discover('https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration');

  const client = new issuer.Client({
    client_id: '<client-id>',
    client_secret: '<client-secret>',
    redirect_uris: ['http://localhost:3000/callback'], 
  });

...
```

openid-client version: 5.4.3

Answer (score 0):

Use the base URL as the issuer URL:

- https://accounts.google.com

The library will add the relative path to the discovery endpoint for you.

Answer (score 0):

There's [**Quick start**](https://github.com/panva/node-openid-client#quick-start) section in `openid-client`'s README, that shows code example:

> Discover an Issuer configuration using its published .well-known endpoints
>
> ```
> import { Issuer } from 'openid-client';
>
> const googleIssuer = await Issuer.discover('https://accounts.google.com');
> ```

Also, gigging further into the source code, [it actually adds the `.well-known/…` part automatically](https://github.com/panva/node-openid-client/blob/main/lib/issuer.js#L162-L167).